# What is the logic behind this authentication in Firebase for Flutter?

Tags: firebase, dart, google-signin, flutter

I'm following the [Firebase for Flutter Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/) and on the [8th step](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#7) there's this `_ensureLoggedIn()` function:

```
final _googleSignIn = new GoogleSignIn();
final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

Future<Null> _ensureLoggedIn() async {
  GoogleSignInAccount user = _googleSignIn.currentUser;
  if (user == null)
    user = await _googleSignIn.signInSilently();
  if (user == null) {
    await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    analytics.logLogin();                                    
  }

  if (await auth.currentUser() == null) {
    GoogleSignInAuthentication credentials =
        await _googleSignIn.currentUser.authentication;
    await auth.signInWithGoogle(
      idToken: credentials.idToken,
      accessToken: credentials.accessToken,
    );
  }
}
```

As a newbie to both Flutter and Firebase frameworks, i'm really struggling to understand the logic behind it: First we attempt to log the user with the `GoogleSignIn` package, and then regardless of what we will have in `user` we try to auth the user again with `FirebaseAuth`, which in turn will also use the `GoogleSignIn`.

Could you explain me why we do both?
My target is to have two separate screens for users who open my app - one for unauthorized/anonymous (which will have Log In and Register options), and one for authorized users that will see the normal app interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The login example in that Codelab seems poorly written, as the user can potentially cancel the non-silent `signIn()` and then `googleSignIn.currentUser` will be null when they try to access `googleSignIn.currentUser.authentication`. I think a better way to handle it is trigger the Google sign in and handle the Firebase auth in in the `googleSignIn.onAuthStateChanged` listener.

**As for why both are used in that example:** If you want to authenticate a user on Firebase with a Google account you have to provide an `idToken` and `accessToken`, which must be obtained from a valid Google login. So first, you have them sign in to their Google account (via `googleSignIn`) and use the tokens from that to authenticate with Firebase (via `auth`).

Using `googleSignIn` is only required if you want to authenticate with Firebase using a Google account; you can also use Firebase Auth with a username/password combination (which requires that the account be created on Firebase first) or with a token from a Facebook login, or some other OAuth token.